# When child_added complete will do something

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I need help with Firebase, in my project I have many room. When member choose room it will scroll to bottom. But function scroll to bottom run before `child_added` append. How can I do function scroll to bottom when `child_added` had completed?. If i add alert in `displayChatMessage`, it always alert first and when done, it will append

```
myDataRef.limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function (snapshot,prevChildKey){
  var message = snapshot.val();
 displayChatMessage(snapshot.key, message.name, message.text');

});

function displayChatMessage(key,name,text){
 var html = '<div id="'+key+'">'+name+'</div>';
$('#addhere').append(html);
}
```

Comment: please tell which front end client you are using

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `asynchronous` execution.When you execute something `synchronously`, you wait for it to finish before moving on to another task. When you execute something `asynchronously`, you can move on to another task before it finishes.
In your case you need to call your function `scroll_to_bottom()` after `displayChatMessage` append & for that you should use callback.
See the below example of using callback ..

global variable​

```
​var allUserData = [];
```

​generic logStuff function that prints to console​

```
​function logStuff (userData) {
if ( typeof userData === "string")
{
    console.log(userData);
}
else if ( typeof userData === "object")
{
    for (var item in userData) {
        console.log(item + ": " + userData[item]);
    }
}}
```

​
// A function that takes two parameters, the last one a callback function

```
function getInput (options, callback) {
allUserData.push (options);
callback (options);
}
```

​
​// When we call the getInput function, we pass logStuff as a parameter.​
​// So logStuff will be the function that will called back (or executed) inside the getInput function​

```
getInput ({name:"Rich", speciality:"JavaScript"}, logStuff);
```

​//  name: Rich​
​// speciality: JavaScript`

Comment: Hi Phuc Vo !!
You can also accept my answer, If its helpful for you :)